# How to version & publish snapshot/not-finished work on a go module?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm new in Golang, and I'm trying to develop a go-module and share it with my colleagues while I'm developing it; In JVM/sbt I used to publish my work with a 'SNAPSHOT' postfixed to version value. but How I can achieve the same in with go-modules?

Answer (score 0):

Versions for modules are tagged by using repo tags (e.g. `git tag`), following semantic versioning (https://semver.org/).

So, any version starting with `v0` is treated as unstable and may make breaking changes at any time. Once you release a `v1`, you cannot make any breaking changes without bumping your major version, which also means you change your module name.

You also have the option of appending `+foo` to the end of your version to indicate additional information about the version.

I wrote https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules as an overview of how to get started using modules.